# Redux test using react-testing-library fails

Tags: typescript, react-redux, react-testing-library

I am testing a hook that internally dispatchs an action to fetch data and then it returns the value using the selector. I am using the approach suggested by react-testing-library and I am testing the return values of the hook in a component (avoiding testing implementation details)
The action follows the traditional fetching pattern. So the state goes from `{inProgress: false, error: false, data: null}` to `{inProgress: true, error: false, data: null}` to `{inProgress: true, error: false, data: Object}` in case of success.

I am testing the case in which the API returns a value.
The problem that I have is that the first expect of my test is checked once inProgress is already true so the test fails. It seems that the test is skipping the initial inProgress = false.

The test has the following structure:

```
     // should show inProgress false when the component renders first time
     expect(screen.getByText(/false/i)).toBeInTheDocument();     
     // after a while, it should now show that it is fetching the data (inProgress = true)
     expect(await screen.findByText(/true/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
     // after some time, the data should be received (inProgress = false)
     expect(await screen.findByText(/false/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
```

I have written the code in a sandbox so you can check the code and see how the test fails. I have added some console.logs so you are able to see that the test is skipping the firs inProgress = false.

https://codesandbox.io/s/n4s74

The test is in components/hooks folder. The hook tested is `useGetRecommendedActionsSummarySelector`.

I don't know if it is an error of the test or a bug. Of course, the code that is being tested works perfectly fine.